# Different information domains in DB

Tags: database-design

I have a database for my personal site and at the moment it is storing different domains of information (Eg cv, CMS schema, and more, all in one DB).

I have noticed that sets of tables (eg all for one domain) have no relationship to other groups of tables as they are completely unrelated. What implication does this have on database design? I can assume this is a time I need to think about having >1 DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have hosting that allows for plenty of DBs, use plenty of DBs.

I was "frugal" with my DB usage (I had a bunch of tables from unrelated packages in a single DB).  Then I started running into performance issues (I was on a shared server, and the DBs were hosted elsewhere).  I had to split them up, which took some time.

I still have a lot of unused DBs on my hosting package and my projects are far easier to maintain, and they behave better, too.

Re-using a DB like this is a bit like compressing 100 MB of e-mail when you have a 1 TB drive.  If you have room for more DBs, use them.

Comment: I should have added that I to am on shared hosting and have to pay £10/m per extra DB. That's why I have followed this approach.

Comment: Ouch.  But to answer your question, I don't see it making a whole lot of difference, I suppose, as long as you don't see performance issues because of the size of the (one) DB.  The tables within won't care about the other ones.